# Send an Email to salesforce user from salesforce account

Tags: email

how can I build an Email sending feature within salesforce users?

e.g. I have logged in as an sales@force.com and I have an multiple users associated with me I want to send an email from my user list through an salesforce API not from console.

Please let me know if is there any API, Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem using SFIdentityData which is given in salesforce core API package,which is after digging/hunting more into the SDK of salesforce.But I didn't found any API reference specification for salesforce.